# Why doesn't my curl command execute via cron?

Tags: curl, cron

This runs via command line:

`` m=`time ( my_command &> /dev/null) 2>&1` && curl -d "m=$m" https://nosnch.in/foo_token ``

But when run via cron, my_command executes, but the curl command does not.

My cron log has the following output:

`` Nov 22 21:10:01 cron1 CROND[3016]: (root) CMD (m=`time ( my_command &> /dev/null) 2>&1` && curl -d "m=$m" "https://nosnch.in/foo_token") ``

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

99% of problems in *nix are path or permissions.

Have you set a path in your cron, or have you tried the full path to the curl command? I've had many cron jobs fail because the path was assumed, but you sometimes need to put the full path in so the cron demon (which has no environment usually) can find it. That goes for every executable, so replace time and curl with their full paths.

Comment: Adding the full path was the fix. Thanks!